# Merging data frames while excluding empty records

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am merging the two `data frames` on the basis of matching `website`. But there are few records in both data frames which do not have a website. This results in wrong matching in my resultant data frame because it also matches the records in which both the website field is empty. How can I put a condition where it does not match the empty strings?

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on='website1',right_on='website2').sort_values('company_name')
```

---

Comment: Filter the rows out before merging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter before merging by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df1[df1.website1 != '']
df2 = df2[df2.website2 != '']
```

Sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'website1':['','aa','bb'],
                   'a':[4,5,6]})

print (df1)
   a website1
0  4         
1  5       aa
2  6       bb

df1 = df1[df1.website1 != '']
print (df1)
   a website1
1  5       aa
2  6       bb
```